# Differences between Java 6 and Java 7 in ArrayList capacity growth

Tags: java, math, arraylist

I have a question about how *ArrayList's capacity growth* (not the size, but the capacity) is managed in Java.
When we initialize an ArrayList using the default constructor without setting a capacity, the capacity is set = 10 by default.

At this point, when we add another element to the list, the Oracle documentation says that "As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost."

If we look at Java internals the capacity growth policy has changed its function. Until Java 6 it was:

```
(1) int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
```

From Java 7 (and > 7) it is:

```
(2) int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
```

but these two mathematical series are slightly different. Starting from the default value (10) we have:

(1) 10,16,25,38,58,88,133,200,301,452...

(2) 10,15,22,33,49,73,109,163,244,366...

I think that this hasn't any implication on ArrayList use, but why did they change this function? Is there any performance reason? Did they find a flaw or a bug in the old one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenJDK's [source control history](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/annotate/ec45423a4700/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l202) shows it was changed by [Martin Buchholz from Google](https://db.openjdk.java.net/people) in [changeset 2350](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/ec45423a4700) to fix bug [JDK-6933217: Huge arrays handled poorly in core libraries](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6933217).

The new code is careful to avoid unnecessary integer overflow. `oldCapacity * 3` can overflow even if `oldCapacity * 3 / 2` doesn't. The new line `oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1)` won't. And if it does overflow and go negative there's additional code to set the capacity to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or near to it).

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate.
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;

private void grow(int minCapacity) {
    // overflow-conscious code
    int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
    int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
    if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
        newCapacity = minCapacity;
    if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
        newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
    // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
    elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
}

private static int hugeCapacity(int minCapacity) {
    if (minCapacity < 0) // overflow
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    return (minCapacity > MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ?
        Integer.MAX_VALUE :
        MAX_ARRAY_SIZE;
}
```

Full details from the [bug report](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6933217):

> I've noticed bugs in `java.util.ArrayList`, `java.util.Hashtable` and
>   `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream` which arise when the capacities of the
>   data structures reach a particular threshold.  More below.
>
> When the capacity of an `ArrayList` reaches `(2/3)*Integer.MAX_VALUE` its
>   size reaches its capacity and an add or an insert operation is
>   invoked, the capacity is increased by only one element.  Notice that
>   in the following excerpt from `ArrayList.ensureCapacity` the new
>   capacity is set to `(3/2) * oldCapacity + 1` unless this value would not
>   suffice to accommodate the required capacity in which case it is set
>   to the required capacity.  If the current capacity is at least
>   `(2/3)*Integer.MAX_VALUE`, then `(oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1` overflows and
>   resolves to a negative number resulting in the new capacity being set
>   to the required capacity.  The major consequence of this is that each
>   subsequent add/insert operation results in a full resize of the
>   `ArrayList` causing performance to degrade significantly.
>
> ```
> int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
> if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
>     newCapacity = minCapacity;
> ```
>
> ...
>
> It is interesting to note that any statements about the amortized time
>   complexity of add/insert operations, such as the one in the `ArrayList`
>   javadoc, are invalidated by the performance related bugs.  One
>   solution to the above situations is to set the new capacity of the
>   backing array to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` when the initial size calculation
>   results in a negative number during a resize.